# How to customize UINavigationBar only for certain view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Would customize UINavigationBar

Say I have a class

```
BGImageBookController
```

I want UINavigationBar on top of BGImageBookController to have a different background. How would I do so?

I did this in viewDidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[BGImageBookController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sushi_eating_cat"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

no effect

Comment: Stackoverflow says: "You should mark an answer accepted if it helped you solve your problem".

Comment: I will once I got some explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[BGImageBookController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: The problem is, UINavigationBar is simply not contained in BGImgeBookController class. BGImageBookController class is in the UINavigationBar

Comment: But your question says you want your navigation bar from BGImgeBookController be customized. So in this case, what do you want to obtain? Where is your navigation bar situated?

Comment: I think you should first identify which UINavigationController navigation bar do you want to customize.

Comment: Well I suppose UINavigationController contains both BGImageBookController and UINavigationBar

Comment: Sorry, I meant which UIViewController's navigation bar you want to adjust. The view controller should be in the navigation stack. It means that you push this UIViewController on the stack.

Comment: I post my viewDidLoad. How exactly I should modify this? I did your code. Doesn't work.

Comment: Usually, this setup is done somewhere in your app delegate, as it applies on the whole application.

Comment: Well I want to do this in viewDidload to maintain code locality.

Comment: Than you should do it, in the viewDidLoad of the navigation controller you're pushing on the stack like so:     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1):

You just call `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the `BGImageBookController`.

Comment: How do I access the UINavigationBar object? Is that a property of BGImageBookController?

Comment: Is that a property of UIViewController.